# Determine if you have line, bingo or nothing in a 3x3 bingo game

Tags: c#

I have this problem of bingo, where I have to check for bingo, line, or nothing, for a given input, where I get the 3 X 3 bingo card, and next 15 numbers extracted.

Here is the input:

- 1 2 3
- 4 5 6
- 7 8 9
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 10
- 11
- 12
- 13
- 14
- 15
- 16

I wrote the following code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int numberOfRows = 3;
        const int numberOfColumnns = 3;
        const int numbersExtracted = 15;
        int[,] bingoCard = ReadBingoCard(numberOfRows, numberOfColumnns);
        int[] numbers = ReadNumbersExtracted(numbersExtracted);
        PrintResult(bingoCard, numbers);
    }

    static int[,] ReadBingoCard(int rowsNumber, int columnNumber)
    {
        int[,] card = new int[rowsNumber, columnNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
        {
            string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            for (int j = 0; j < columnNumber; j++)
            {
                card[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(array[j]);
            }
        }

        return card;
    }

    static int[] ReadNumbersExtracted(int numbersExtracted)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[numbersExtracted];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersExtracted; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        int numMatchesFound = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
                {
                    if (bingoCard[row, col] == numbers[numIndex])
                    {
                        numMatchesFound++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
    }

    static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            int colMatchesInRow = 0;

            for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
                {
                    if (bingoCard[row, col] != numbers[numIndex])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    colMatchesInRow++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (colMatchesInRow == bingoCard.GetLength(1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    static void PrintResult(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
    {
        if (CheckForBingo(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bingo");
        }
        else if (CheckForLine(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("linie");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nimic");
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the analyzers that I use, I have some limitations. I cannot compile the program because it is giving me the error: "S134-Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 control flow statements" for the CheckForBingo and CheckForLine functions. A suggestion of how I could get rid of it would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: Thanks for this. I think that my methods works properly if I wouldn`t had those limitations. My question is about how I could rewrite those methods by not having more than 3 control flow statements"

Comment: What if there was no matrix, no 2D array. Store bingo in a list. 2 D array is just for display. No more nested loop, single look up. Index of line and columns is a simple modulo.

Comment: The code is not accepted by the platform. I get the message : ""Array does not have that many dimensions."

Comment: Can you just remove the inner loop that goes over the numbers and instead use: `if (numbers.Contains(bingoCard[row, col]))`

Comment: I`m not allowed to use Linq.

Comment: So basiclly i have bingo if checkcolumns, checkrows and checkdiagonals are true?

Comment: The cognitive complexity for checkdiagonals method is 20, and I`m allowd 15. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a single dimension array instead of a multi-dimensional array, and then use math to determine the row and column of an item based on its index.

If you think about your multi-dimensional array, you have the following indexes:

```
0,0   0,1   0,2
1,0   1,1   1,2
2,0   2,1   2,2
```

If we instead use a single-dimensional array, but layed it out in a similar row/column format, it will look like this:

```
0   1   2
3   4   5
6   7   8
```

So the challenge is to determine which row and column an index belongs to. Since we know the row count and column count, we can do this mathematically. For each index, we can determine which row it's on by dividing it by the number of columns.

`int row = index / colCount;`

To get the column of a specified index, we can use the modulus operator in a similar manner:

`int col = index % colCount;`

With this trick, we can loop through a single-dimensional array and determine the row and column of each item based on its index, which will allow us to check for BINGO on rows, columns, and diagonals.

Creating the array in the first place changes slightly. We set the number of items to `rowCount * colCount`, and then when we add an item, since we have to do it in two loops of rows and columns, we can use `col + (row * colCount)` to determine the index for the current item:

```
static int[] ReadBingoCard(int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    int[] card = new int[rowCount * colCount];

    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
        {
            card[col + (row * colCount)] = Convert.ToInt32(input[col]);
        }
    }

    return card;
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you on the right track. If not, read on below for some more implementation, but try it yourself first!

---

Here's how you can use this method to determine if there are matches on the rows, columns, and diagonals:

```
static bool CheckRows(int[] bingoCard, int colCount, int[] numbers)
{
    int rowMatches = 0;
    int currentRow = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < bingoCard.Length; index++)
    {
        int thisRow = index / colCount;

        // If we're starting a new row, reset our counter
        if (thisRow != currentRow)
        {
            currentRow = thisRow;
            rowMatches = 0;
        }

        for (int num = 0; num < numbers.Length; num++)
        {
            if (bingoCard[index] == numbers[num])
            {
                rowMatches++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (rowMatches == colCount) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

static bool CheckColumns(int[] bingoCard, int colCount, int[] numbers)
{
    int[] colMatches = new int[colCount];
    int rowCount = bingoCard.Length / colCount;

    for (int index = 0; index < bingoCard.Length; index++)
    {
        int thisCol = index % colCount;

        for (int num = 0; num < numbers.Length; num++)
        {
            if (bingoCard[index] == numbers[num])
            {
                colMatches[thisCol]++;
                    
                if (colMatches[thisCol] == rowCount) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

static bool CheckDiagonals(int[]bingoCard, int colCount, int[]numbers)
{
    int diagMatches = 0;

    // Check first diagonal, from upper left to bottom right
    for (int index = 0; index < bingoCard.Length; index += (colCount + 1))
    {
        for (int num = 0; num < numbers.Length; num++)
        {
            if (bingoCard[index] == numbers[num])
            {
                diagMatches++;

                if (diagMatches == colCount) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Check second diagonal, from upper right to bottom left
    diagMatches = 0;

    for (int index = colCount - 1; index < bingoCard.Length; index += (colCount - 1))
    {
        for (int num = 0; num < numbers.Length; num++)
        {
            if (bingoCard[index] == numbers[num])
            {
                diagMatches++;

                if (diagMatches == colCount) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```